next-sitemap not including my blog posts and pages in sitemap
I am building a blog with Next.js and Contentlayer, but my sitemap generated using next-sitemap is not including the blog posts and other important pages.
blog/[slug]/page.js:


import BlogDetails from "@/app/_blog-component/Blog/BlogDetails";
import RenderMdx from "@/app/_blog-component/Blog/RenderMdx";
import siteMetadata from "@/utils/siteMetaData";
import { allBlogs } from "contentlayer/generated";
import { slug } from "github-slugger";
import Image from "next/image";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
return allBlogs.map((blog) => ({ slug: blog._raw.flattenedPath }));
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
const blog = allBlogs.find((blog) => blog._raw.flattenedPath === params.slug);
if (!blog) {
return;
}

const publishedAt = new Date(blog.publishedAt).toISOString();
const modifiedAt = new Date(blog.updatedAt || blog.publishedAt).toISOString();

let imageList = [siteMetadata.socialBanner];
if (blog.image) {
imageList =
typeof blog.image.filePath === "string"
? [siteMetadata.siteUrl + blog.image.filePath.replace("../public", "")]
: blog.image;
}
const ogImages = imageList.map((img) => {
return { url: img.includes("http") ? img : siteMetadata.siteUrl + img };
});

const authors = blog?.author ? [blog.author] : siteMetadata.author;

return {
title: blog.title,
description: blog.description,
openGraph: {
title: blog.title,
description: blog.description,
url: siteMetadata.siteUrl + blog.url,
siteName: siteMetadata.title,
locale: "en_US",
type: "article",
publishedTime: publishedAt,
modifiedTime: modifiedAt,
images: ogImages,
authors: authors.length > 0 ? authors : [siteMetadata.author],
},
twitter: {
card: "summary_large_image",
title: blog.title,
description: blog.description,
images: ogImages,
},
};
}

export default async function BlogPage({ params }) {
const blog = allBlogs.find((blog) => blog._raw.flattenedPath === params.slug);

if (!blog) {
notFound();
}

const imagePath = blog.image?.filePath ? blog.image.filePath.replace("../public", "") : "";
const blurUrl = blog.image?.blurhashDataUrl || "";
const imageWidth = blog.image?.width || 1200;
const imageHeight = blog.image?.height || 630;

const jsonLd = {
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BlogPosting",
"headline": blog.title,
"description": blog.description,
"image": imagePath ? [imagePath] : [],
"datePublished": new Date(blog.publishedAt).toISOString(),
"dateModified": new Date(blog.updatedAt || blog.publishedAt).toISOString(),
"author": [{
"@type": "Person",
"name": blog?.author ? blog.author : siteMetadata.author,
"url": siteMetadata.twitter,
}]
}

return (
<>
<script
type="application/ld+json"
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
/>
<article>
<div className="mb-8 text-center relative w-full h-[70vh] bg-dark">
<div className="w-full z-10 flex flex-col items-center justify-center absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">
<h1 className="inline-block mt-6 font-semibold capitalize text-light text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl !leading-normal relative w-5/6">
{blog.title}
</h1>
</div>
<div className="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 h-full bg-dark/60 dark:bg-dark/40" />
{imagePath && (
<Image
src={imagePath}
placeholder="blur"
blurDataURL={blurUrl}
alt={blog.title}
width={imageWidth}
height={imageHeight}
className="aspect-square w-full h-full object-cover object-center"
priority
sizes="100vw"
/>
)}
</div>
<BlogDetails blog={blog} slug={params.slug} />
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-y-8 lg:gap-8 sxl:gap-16 mt-8 px-5 md:px-10">
<div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-4">
<details
className="border-[1px] border-solid border-dark dark:border-light text-dark dark:text-light rounded-lg p-4 sticky top-6 max-h-[80vh] overflow-hidden overflow-y-auto"
open
>
<summary className="text-lg font-semibold capitalize cursor-pointer">
Table Of Content
</summary>
<ul className="mt-4 font-in text-base">
{blog.toc.map((heading) => {
return (
<li key={`#${heading.slug}`} className="py-1">
<a
href={`#${heading.slug}`}
data-level={heading.level}
className="data-[level=two]:pl-0 data-[level=two]:pt-2
data-[level=two]:border-t border-solid border-dark/40
data-[level=three]:pl-4
sm:data-[level=three]:pl-6
flex items-center justify-start"
>
{heading.level === "three" ? (
<span className="flex w-1 h-1 rounded-full bg-dark mr-2">
&nbsp;
</span>
) : null}
<span className="hover:underline">{heading.text}</span>
</a>
</li>
);
})}
</ul>
</details>
</div>
<RenderMdx blog={blog} />
</div>
</article>
</>
);
}


contentlayer.config.js:
I have defined the Blog document type and included a computed field url to resolve the paths of the blog posts:

import { makeSource, defineDocumentType } from "@contentlayer/source-files";
import rehypePrettyCode from "rehype-pretty-code";
import rehypeSlug from "rehype-slug";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import GithubSlugger from "github-slugger"

const Blog = defineDocumentType(() => ({
name: "Blog",
filePathPattern: "**/**/*.mdx",
contentType: "mdx",
fields: {
title: {
type: "string",
required: true,
},
publishedAt: {
type: "date",
required: true,
},
updatedAt: {
type: "date",
required: true,
},
description: {
type: "string",
required: true,
},
image: { type: "image" },
isPublished: {
type: "boolean",
default: true,
},
author: {
type: "string",
required: true,
},
// tags: {
// type: "list",
// of: { type: "string" },
// },
},
computedFields: {
url: {
type: "string",
resolve: (doc) => `/blog/${doc._raw.flattenedPath}`,
},
// readingTime: {
// type: "json",
// resolve: (doc) => readingTime(doc.body.raw)
// },
toc:{
type: "json",
resolve: async (doc) => {

const regulrExp = /\n(?<flag>#{1,6})\s+(?<content>.+)/g;
const slugger = new GithubSlugger();
const headings = Array.from(doc.body.raw.matchAll(regulrExp)).map(({groups}) => {
const flag = groups?.flag;
const content = groups?.content;

return {
level: flag?.length == 1 ? "one" : flag?.length == 2 ? "two" : "three",
text: content,
slug: content ? slugger.slug(content) : undefined
}

})

return headings;
}
}
},
}));

const codeOptions = {
theme: 'github-dark',
grid: false,
}

export default makeSource({
/* options */
contentDirPath: "content",
documentTypes: [Blog],
disableImportAliasWarning: true,
mdx: { remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm] , rehypePlugins: [ rehypeSlug, [rehypePrettyCode, codeOptions] ] }
});


next-sitemap.config.js:

const siteMetadata = require("./utils/siteMetaData");

module.exports = {
siteUrl: siteMetadata.siteUrl,
generateRobotsTxt: true,
}


BlogDetails.js:

import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { slug } from "github-slugger";

const BlogDetails = ({ blog, slug: blogSlug }) => {
return (
<div className="px-2 md:px-10 bg-accent dark:bg-accentDark text-light dark:text-dark py-2 flex items-center justify-around flex-wrap text-lg sm:text-xl font-medium mx-5 md:mx-10 rounded-lg">
<time className="m-3">
{format(parseISO(blog.publishedAt), "LLLL d, yyyy")}
</time>
{/* <div className="m-3">{blog.readingTime.text}</div> */}
{/* <Link href={`/categories/${slug(blog.tags[0])}`} className="m-3">
#{blog.tags[0]}
</Link> */}
</div>
);
};

export default BlogDetails;


Output:

http://localhost:3000/sitemap-0.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url><loc>http://localhost:3000/robots.txt</loc><lastmod>2024-12-25T18:16:00.010Z</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority></url>
<url><loc>http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml</loc><lastmod>2024-12-25T18:16:00.010Z</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority></url>
</urlset>



However, when I generate the sitemap, it does not include blog posts or other pages, only static URLs like /sitemap.xml and /robots.txt.
How can I configure next-sitemap to include dynamically generated blog posts and important pages in the sitemap?
Is there a specific integration step required for Contentlayer with next-sitemap?
Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
